# $_post['value'] exists but when I check it with empty it returns false

Tags: php

I have a post-variable that has to be checked whether it is empty or not. I look at the value of the variable like this:

```
print_r($_POST['arrayId']);
```

and it prints the expected value.
However if I do this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['arrayId'])) {
    // some stuff
} else {
    echo "f";
}
```

f is printed, and the code that should be executed isn't. How is this possible?

Comment: What is "the expected value"?

Comment: Somewhat impossible, what does `$_POST['arrayId']` is? `0` ?

Comment: it's an array key, this time it was 0

Comment: Oh 0 is regarded as empty. How can I check if it is not empty even if the value is 0 ?

Comment: `isset($_POST['arrayId']) && strlen($_POST['arrayId'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this instead, it will check if the key is present in the post array, regardless of the value. also works for `NULL`, `false`, `0` and any other values which are treated as "empty" values...

```
if(array_key_exists('arrayId', $_POST)) {
    // some stuff
} else {
    echo "f";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`empty()` returns true if value is `0`.

change with:

```
if(isset($_POST['arrayId']) && strlen($_POST['arrayId'])) {
    // some stuff
} else {
    echo "f";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Verify input'$var' to empty() function

> empty($var)
>
> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value.
>   Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> "" (an empty string)  0 (0 as an integer) 
>   0.0 (0 as a float)  "0" (0 as a string)  NULL  FALSE  array() (an empty array)  $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php